# How can I get the environment variable from docker file

Tags: linux, docker, jmeter, docker-compose, jmeter-4.0

How can I get the environment variable from docker file for example I am adding a

```
ENV URL_PATH="google.com"
```

in my `dockerfile`, so can I get the this `URL_PATH` in my `Jmeter.jmx` file with the help of User Defined Variable.

On window its working fine with proper `{__env(URL_PATH)}`

but on docker its not working. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `-e` option to pass environment variables into the container when running it.

```
docker run -e URL_PATH=google.com ...
```

Docs: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#env-environment-variables

Comment: Is this compatible for Linux +terminal

Comment: I think this is for windows, but I am using Linux

Comment: Docker Code:- 
RUN -e URL_PATH=google.com

COPY entrypoint.sh /
WORKDIR ${JMETER_HOME}
COPY  sample.jmx ./
RUN ls -l
RUN echo $PATH
# ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD jmeter -JJmeter_Result=$Jmeter_Result
CMD jmeter -n -t sample.jmx -l sample.csv -e -o sample.html

Comment: I am passing in jmeter User Defined Varibale :- {__env(URL_PATH)}     <stringProp name="Argument.value">${__env(URL_PATH)}</stringProp>

Comment: My Docker File Screenshot :- https://www.dropbox.com/s/05lz2r2jzdd0dz4/Untitled.png?dl=0    can you please check and update me

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see [__env() is a Custom JMeter Function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#envsupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-2-0-font-sup) therefore it is **not available** in vanilla JMeter so the options are in:

1. Amend your `Dockerfile` to include downloading of http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/kg/apc/jmeter-plugins-functions/2.0/jmeter-plugins-functions-2.0.jar to "lib/ext". This way you will be able to use __env() function in Docker environment normally. See [Make Use of Docker with JMeter - Learn How](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/make-use-of-docker-with-jmeter-learn-how) for example Docker configuration assuming using JMeter with Plugins.
2. Switch to [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy). Replace all the occurrences of `{__env(URL_PATH)}` with the following expression:

   ```
   ${__groovy(System.getenv('URL_PATH'),)}
   ```

Comment: The second option saved my day, thank you.